# Creating dataframe by merging a number of unknown length dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am trying to do some analysis on baseball pitch F/x data. All the pitch data is stored in a pandas dataframe with columns like 'Pitch speed' and 'X location.' I have a wrapper function (using pandas.query) that, for a given pitch, will find other pitches with similar speed and location. This function returns a pandas dataframe of unknown size. I would like to use this function over large numbers of pitches; for example, to find all pitches similar to those thrown in a single game. I have a function that does this correctly, but it is quite slow (probably because it is constantly resizing resampled_pitches):

```
def get_pitches_from_templates(template_pitches, all_pitches):
    resampled_pitches = pd.DataFrame(columns = all_pitches.columns.values.tolist())
    for i, row in template_pitches.iterrows():
        resampled_pitches = resampled_pitches.append( get_pitches_from_template( row, all_pitches))
    return resampled_pitches
```

I have tried to rewrite the function using pandas.apply on each row, or by creating a list of dataframes and then merging, but can't quite get the syntax right.

What would be the fastest way to this type of sampling and merging?

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you should use `pd.concat` for this.

```
res = []
for i, row in template_pitches.iterrows():
    res.append(resampled_pitches.append(get_pitches_from_template(row, all_pitches)))
return pd.concat(res)
```

Comment: I used your suggestions today, and it reduced a test runtime from 22 seconds to 15, which is pretty good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that **a merge** might be even faster. Usage of `df.iterrows()` isn't recommended as it generates a series for every row.

Comment: What is a better way to apply the function to each row?

Comment: @MichaelIP you don't need to iterate throw the rows. Just do an inner merge and discards all the `NA`